# eth0 'bricked' - no link light despite fresh install of Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, ethernet, ethernet-port

I am currently working on a project to set up a Pi 3 to serve DHCP leases to devices that connect to an isolated local network to configure them. In the process I have somehow managed to render `eth0` unable to bind any IPv4 address on two separate Pi's. All other I/O remains unaffected, including Wi-Fi. In both cases I had `dnsmasq` installed and the problem presented itself after adjusting its config file and setting a static IP for the `eth0` interface.

The first Pi was using a static IP set in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and a minimal set of options enabled in `dnsmasq`. The second one to fail (two weeks later) had `dhcpcd` disabled in favor of using `/etc/network/interfaces` and bridging rules between `wlan0` and `eth0` set using `iptables`. I also had more options set in `dnsmasq` on the second device to facilitate this.

What really confuses me, and what prompted me to ask for help here, is the fact that neither an SD card with a fresh Raspbian image nor one with a clean NOOBS installer has resolved this issue. Furthermore, either of those SD cards when placed in another fully-functional Pi 3 enable `eth0` to bind to whatever IP my network's DHCP server assigns it, as one would expect with any "out-of-the-box" setup.

Let me know if you'd like more specific information, e.g. see a certain file(s) or logs, etc.

Comment: Could you check the USB port to see if 5v is there or not? I mean the 4 USB ports, the USB and Ethernet are controlled by the smsc95xx chip on the board, perhaps it's dead so it won't put out any voltage to USB port neither doing any ethernet job. The chip only power on the USB ports if the OS has loaded the smsc module so either the kernel is corrupted or the chip has dead